# jQuery UI Sortable child triggers

Tags: jquery-ui, tinymce, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list like so:

```
<ol id="page_items">        
    <li>
        <label for="page_body_1">Content Area 1</label>
        <textarea name="page_body_1" class="page_content_area" rows="10"></textarea>
    </li>           
    <li>
        <label for="page_body_2">Content Area 2</label>
        <textarea name="page_body_2" class="page_content_area" rows="10"></textarea>
    </li>     
</ol>
```

When the page loads, `#page_items` turns into a tinyMCE editor.  What I want is for the element that defines whether or not the `li` elements are being sorted to be the `<label>` but no other child elements of `li`. So the only element that starts the sort is the label.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#page_items").sortable({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            var EditorID = ui.item.find('textarea').attr('id');
            if ( EditorID ){ 
                tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", false, EditorID);
                $('#'+EditorID).hide();
            }
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var EditorID = ui.item.find('textarea').attr('id');
            if ( EditorID ){ 
                    $('#'+EditorID).show();
                tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, EditorID);
                delete EditorID;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In case anyone is wondering, I'm disabling the tinyMCE because in FireFox, moving an iFrame around the DOM clears it's contents and doesn't allow focus back on it.

Is there a way to cancel the sortable if the element clicked isn't the label?

If anyone has any code clean-up suggestions they are also welcome!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a sortable option that I didn't see before (I looked... oh I looked). The `handle` option is what I need. This initializes a sortable with the handle option specified.

Simply...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#page_items").sortable({
        handle: 'label'
    });
});
```